# Set the release version for NetBeans RCP application Windows installer

Tags: netbeans-platform, maven-nbm

I am building a NetBeans RCP application using the NetBeans platform version 7.3 and the maven-nbm-plugin. For Windows, I'm building an installer using the `nbm:build-installers` mojo. The installer produced installs my application, but the version number listed in the Windows `Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features` is 1.0.0.0. When I build a new version of the application, users are unable to install it because Windows believes the version (1.0.0.0) is already installed. I know that I can use NetBeans' auto-update functionality, but I also want users to be able to run a full install for updates.

How can I configure the maven-nbm-plugin to set the release version number of the Windows installer's installed product? Ideally, I'd like to use the Maven `${project.version}` of the application module as the release version.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem today, and after I changed these lines

1. `product.version` on `{nbdir}\harness\nbi\stub\ext\infra\build\products\helloworld\build.properties`
2. `version` attribute on `create-bundle > component` on `{nbdir}\harness\nbi\stub\build.xml`

with the **same** value (your new version), I can use my new installer to install the newer app side-by-side with older app.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This answer (while correct) applies to Ant based projects, not Maven based projects. The OP seems to have a Maven project.